# Async with WPF properties

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I have a bound property like this:

```
public string MyPath
{
    get { return _mypath; }
    set
    {
        _mypath = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(() => MyPath);
        LoadSomeStuffFromMyPath(mypath)
    }
}
```

I'd like the make LoadSomeStuffFromMyPath async but I cannot await from a property. Is there a simple way to do this?

EDIT: More than one person has said not to use a property so I want to call this out. I am using WPF and this property is bound to the UI. I have to use a property.

Comment: Is it important for code setting a value to not continue execution until `LoadSomeStuffFromMyPath` finishes?  If no, fire and forget, if yes, don't use a property, use a method to set the value.

Comment: @Servy Yes it is important that it not continue. Unfortunately I'm using WPF so I don't have the option to not use a property.

Comment: @Justin984 If it can't continue, why do you want it to be asynchronous?

Comment: @ReedCopsey I want to show a progress bar

Comment: @Justin984 Is the property *setter* called from UI data binding, or just the getter?  If it's only the getter then have a read only property and a method that sets the underlying value.

Comment: @Servy Both get and set are bound to the UI.

Comment: @Justin984 While this doesn't provide you the exact requested functionality, my new edit should get you the proper behavior (with some other functionality added)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make this run asynchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501952/how-do-i-make-this-run-asynchronously)

Comment: @Servy I'd say that's actually a different issue (since it's somewhat specific to `IEnumerable<T>` bindings, and purely a "get" issue)

Comment: @ReedCopsey What about it is specific to `IEnumerable`?  The answer would apply equally to any other type of data.  Whether it's a get/set issue shouldn't affect the solution, again, it should apply to both, I would think.

Comment: @Servy That's more "how do I bind to data being asynchronously loaded" - this is more "How do I asychronously change my data".  The mechanisms vary quite a bit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you want to force the operation to not continue until this is complete, I would suggest making a method to handle loading and displaying your progress.

You could use *a separate property* to disable the UI while this loads, which could effectively "block" your user until the operation completes:

```
public string MyPath
{
    get { return _mypath; }
    set
    {
        _myPath = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(() => MyPath);
        UpdateMyPathAsync();
    }
}

public async Task UpdateMyPathAsync()
{
    this.EnableUI = false; // Stop user from setting path again....
    await LoadSomeStuffFromMyPathAsync(MyPath); 
    this.EnableUI = true;
}
```

This allows you to still bind, as normal, with WPF, but have your UI reflect that the operation is running (asynchronously) and display progress, etc.

Comment: Won't this cause execution to continue since UpdateMyPathAsync() is not awaited?

Comment: @Justin984 Yes, but disabling the UI will prevent hte user from doing anything - you *can't stop executing from continuing* if you want to allow the UI to update...

Comment: Well I meant anything that comes after UpdateMyPathAsync() will execute immediately. I didn't submit full source, but I have some things after UpdateMyPathAsync that I do not want to execute until the file is loaded.

Comment: @Justin984 Then wrap that in a separate method call that is async, so you can control the order of operations (which is what I did to disable/enable the UI)

Comment: Be aware that with this solution, exceptions raised from `UpdateMyPathAsync` are ignored.

Comment: @StephenCleary Very true - I didn't add any exception handling in here.  You could easily make a FireAndForget method that wraps the exceptions and logs them or does something else if required, and use that on the resulting Task.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should move that kind of logic to a method. You're going against the guidelines for using properties:

> The operation is orders of magnitude slower than a field set would be.
>   If you are even considering providing an **asynchronous version** of an
>   operation to avoid blocking the thread, it is very likely that the
>   operation is too expensive to be a property. In particular, operations
>   that access the network or **the file system** (other than once for
>   initialization) should most likely be methods, not properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx

**EDIT**:
I'm not very experienced with WPF, but I think this might be a way to bind to a method instead of a property:

[Binding a method to a column in datagrid WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818839/binding-a-method-to-a-column-in-datagrid-wpf)

Comment: It's hard to say without context, but given that it's WPF there's good odds that it's used in databinding, which would require it to be a property.  This has been [confirmed by the op](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550402/async-with-wpf-properties#comment29009531_19550402)

Comment: You're right. Even so, I think it's better I leave this here since this is a pretty common misuse of properties, do you agree?

Comment: Personally, no.  If it's clearly not an answer that applies to the question, I find it distracting to have it as an answer.  No, you need to have a property to do the binding, you won't be able to use a method.