# How to optimize DataContext freeze

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, freeze

I can't seem to solve issue with horrible UI freeze when assigning DataContext to Listbox control in WPF.

I have DataTemplate defined in Window.Resources. 
When app starts I load and sort images in List, where ImageInfo holds various information about image that is loaded, including URI path or BitmapImage.

Problem does not lie here however, when I assign this List as DataContext of ListBox control, I get really huge freeze that I can't seem to be able to solve.

```
 <DataTemplate>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="260" Height="360">
            <Border Padding="5" Margin="10" BorderBrush="Orange">
                <Image Source="{Binding image}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
            <Border Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0.70" Height="50" Margin="0,10,10,0"></Border>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
               <!-- 3 buttons -->
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

<ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Columns="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

I assign DataContext like so :

```
 lbGallery.DataContext = lst169;
```

Lists contain more than 10 items.

So far I tried to solve issue by :

- Trying some virtualization options on grid
- Skipping loading image as BitmapImage, and instead using just URI from path
- Using fixed size for grid

I'm sure that problem is not related to code regarding loading files in lst169, because it loads data only once on startup. Using URI instead of BitmapImage assured me that my method for getting image is not problem as well.

It all leads back to setting that DataContext to listbox control.

What is the proper way to do this ?

Thanks!

**EDIT :**

To clarify since my post is confusing many users :

1. Application starts
2. Resource data is loaded into List (3 lists with different images)
3. Once data is fully loaded, I set one fully loaded list as DataContext of ListBox

That is when freeze happens.

Later on user can switch between images by click on a button. I switch DataContext during this time as well. Freeze happens.

So - Freeze is not caused by loading resources on startup. It's caused by setting DataContext of Listbox to a List, when image gets binded to Image control. Regardless if I'm binding BitmapImage type, or URI with absolute path.

Comment: Look for MVVM as early as you can. If freezing is resource loading time, then you have to either do it before displaying main window (splash window "Loading.."), do it asynchronously (e.g. adding items one by one or adding placeholders first and then loading actual images) or use [virtualization](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25070178/1997232).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your tried setting the Image-Binding to IsAsync = true

```
<Image Source="{Binding image, IsAsync=True}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, 
That still causes freeze, just with a slightly different behavior.
I can see containers drawn, then freeze happens, few seconds later images load fully. 

Without IsAsync freeze happens first, then everything shows up.

Comment: If i get it right, you are loading the BitmapImage at startup?
Have you tried freezing the BitmapImages after loading? img.Freeze();
In addition with virtualization that might bring a performance boost.